# Why is this Boost Spirit example not compiling?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction, calculator, boost-spirit

I decided to learn Boost Spirit and started studying look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/). But, I am disappointed because the very first example [calc1.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/calc1.cpp) isn't compiling on my computer and it gives this error message:

```
calc1.cpp: In constructor ‘client::calculator<Iterator>::calculator()’:
calc1.cpp:43:13: error: ‘uint_type’ is not a member of ‘client::qi’
calc1.cpp:43:27: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘uint_’
calc1.cpp:60:17: error: ‘uint_’ was not declared in this scope
calc1.cpp:60:17: note: suggested alternatives:
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/common_terminals.hpp:134:1: note:   ‘boost::spirit::uint_’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/common_terminals.hpp:134:1: note:   ‘boost::spirit::tag::uint_’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/common_terminals.hpp:134:1: note:   ‘boost::spirit::uint_’
```

I added a line like this, but this is not the solution:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/support/common_terminals.hpp>
```

What should i do? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What's your boost version? This example is from 1.51 and it, of course, compiles on 1.51: http://liveworkspace.org/code/0218209d4c3f7475daae44754d4891a6

Comment: I have the latest Spirit which is I guess not 1.51. How can i translate it to the latest version, any idea?

Comment: The latest version of Boost / Spirit is 1.51.0 unless you're using the 1.52.0.beta1. What is the value of `BOOST_VERSION` in `/usr/include/boost/version.hpp`?

Comment: My Boost version is 1.46.1 (#define BOOST_VERSION 104601) and I am using Ubuntu 11.04, I installed the Boost via package manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use an example from Boost 1.51.0 on an installation of Boost 1.46.1.

Instead of the demo you are using, try this one: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/example/qi/calc1.cpp